# CURL POST with version PHP 5.3.10 and libcurl 7.22

Tags: php, curl

With this code

```
        $response = null;

    // CURL configuration
    $ch = curl_init($url);

    // User password to GoMobi API
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, sprintf("%s:%s", self::GO_MOBI_USER, self::GO_MOBI_PASS));

    // Set http method
    switch ($httpMethod)
    {
        case self::HTTP_METHOD_GET:
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
            break;
        case self::HTTP_METHOD_PUT:
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
            break;
        case self::HTTP_METHOD_DELETE:
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'DELETE');
            break;
        case self::HTTP_METHOD_POST:
        default:
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);                
            break;
    }

    // XML data to api
    if (!is_null($xml))
    {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
    }

    // More CURL options
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    // Exec
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

I've called to this URL: https://api-sandbox.instantmobilizer.com/v1/subscription/c1652b83ffb484d0/suspend and with previous version of PHP 5.3.2 and libcurl 7.19.7 and it's OK, but with the PHP 5.3.10 and libcurl 7.22 fails. Error returned is: «400 Bad request. Your browser sent an invalid request.»

Thanks

Comment: Use a network sniffer or `curl()->VERBOSE(1)->STDERR($fh)` to dump and compare the actual HTTP request.

Comment: > POST /v1/subscription/c1652b83ffb484d0/suspend HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic ZGluYWhvc3Rpbmc6SlFpTnJXMlBN
Host: api-sandbox.instantmobilizer.com
Accept: */*
Content-Length: -1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Expect: 100-continue

* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 400 Bad request
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Connection: close
< Content-Type: text/html
< 
* Closing connection #0